# Create contiguous_iterator for custom class

Tags: c++, iterator, c++20, c++-concepts

#### Summary

I have a custom array class:

```cpp
template<typename T, int SIZE>
class Array {
private:
    T mArray[SIZE];
};
```

To enable support for std algorithms, with ranges, I want to create an iterator for this class. It would seem that `std::contiguous_iterator` would be the optimal choice since I can guarantee contiguous memory layout for the data. Following the [iterator tutorial](https://www.internalpointers.com/post/writing-custom-iterators-modern-cpp) I should create a class inside this class. However, I should somehow be (quoted) *"For example, instead of the std::forward_iterator_tag tag you would mark your iterator with the std::forward_iterator concept."*.

I have a hard time figuring out what the syntax would look like for this, and I have been unable to find a post on the web showcasing this.

#### Question

How do I complete the following code snippet to implement `std::contiguous_iterator` for my `Array<T,S>` class?:

```cpp
import <iterator>;

template<typename T, int SIZE>
class Array {
public:
    const T& operator[](int i) { return mArray[i]; }
    T& operator[](int i) { return mArray[i]; }

private:
    T mArray[SIZE];

public:
    struct Iterator {
        Iterator(T* ptr) : mPtr(ptr) {}

    private:
        T* mPtr;
    };

    Iterator begin() { return Iterator(&mArray[0]); }
    Iterator end() { return Iterator(&mArray[SIZE]); }
};
```

**NOTE:** There is *a lot* of operator overloads. An answer is not required to provide all of them. I just need an example syntax for where to place the concept, then I can probably figure out the rest.

Comment: Not an answer, but there is a cheap solution. Pointers count as iterators, so you can just use them.

Comment: `using iterator = T*;`  More specifically, pointers to complete object types [count as contiguous iterators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/contiguous_iterator) (see Notes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Credits

Thanks to @glenn-teitelbaum for pointing me in the right direction. I think I managed to figure out how to do this. It took a long time, so this will hopefully save someone else that trouble.

## [Answering my own question]

The iterator should comply with the `std::contiguous_iterator` concept, so I looked at [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/contiguous_iterator) for the necessary parts. The concept is defined like this:

```cpp
template<class I>
  concept contiguous_iterator =
    std::random_access_iterator<I> &&
    std::derived_from</*ITER_CONCEPT*/<I>, std::contiguous_iterator_tag> &&
    std::is_lvalue_reference_v<std::iter_reference_t<I>> &&
    std::same_as<
      std::iter_value_t<I>, std::remove_cvref_t<std::iter_reference_t<I>>
    > &&
    requires(const I& i) {
      { std::to_address(i) } ->
        std::same_as<std::add_pointer_t<std::iter_reference_t<I>>>;
    };
```

So in order to implement this concept, I must first also implement `std::random_access_iterator`, `std::is_derived_from<[...]>`, `std::is_lvalue_reference_v<[...]>`, and so on. This is a recursive process, especially since `std::random_access_iterator` builds on top of 4 other iterator types. Since this is a C++20 question, I aim to use C++20 features as much as possible (since it greatly simplifies the implementation). This is the complete iterator implementation:

```cpp
template<typename T, int SIZE>
class Array
{
public:
    class Iterator
    {
    public:
        using iterator_category = std::contiguous_iterator_tag;
        using iterator_concept  = std::contiguous_iterator_tag;
        //using difference_type   = std::ptrdiff_t; // Likely the same
        using difference_type = typename std::iterator<
            std::contiguous_iterator_tag, T>::difference_type;
        //using value_type        = T;
        using value_type        = std::remove_cv_t<T>; // Using `T` seems sufficient
        using pointer           = T*;
        using reference         = T&;

        // constructor for Array<T,S>::begin() and Array<T,S>::end()
        Iterator(pointer ptr) : mPtr(ptr) {}

        // std::weakly_incrementable<I>
        Iterator& operator++() { ++mPtr; return *this; }
        Iterator operator++(int) { Iterator tmp = *this; ++(*this); return tmp; }
        Iterator() : mPtr(nullptr/*&mArray[0]*/) {} // TODO: Unsure which is correct!

        // std::input_or_output_iterator<I>
        reference operator*() { return *mPtr; }

        // std::indirectly_readable<I>
        friend reference operator*(const Iterator& it) { return *(it.mPtr); }

        // std::input_iterator<I>
        // No actions were needed here!

        // std::forward_iterator<I>
        // In C++20, 'operator==' implies 'operator!='
        bool operator==(const Iterator& it) const { return mPtr == it.mPtr; }

        // std::bidirectional_iterator<I>
        Iterator& operator--() { --mPtr; return *this; }
        Iterator operator--(int) { Iterator tmp = *this; --(*this); return tmp; }

        // std::random_access_iterator<I>
        //     std::totally_ordered<I>
        std::weak_ordering operator<=>(const Iterator& it) const {
            return std::compare_three_way{}(mPtr, it.mPtr);
            // alternatively: `return mPtr <=> it.mPtr;`
        }
        //     std::sized_sentinel_for<I, I>
        difference_type operator-(const Iterator& it) const { return mPtr - it.mPtr; }
        //     std::iter_difference<I> operators
        Iterator& operator+=(difference_type diff) { mPtr += diff; return *this; }
        Iterator& operator-=(difference_type diff) { mPtr -= diff; return *this; }
        Iterator operator+(difference_type diff) const { return Iterator(mPtr + diff); }
        Iterator operator-(difference_type diff) const { return Iterator(mPtr - diff); }
        friend Iterator operator+(difference_type diff, const Iterator& it) {
            return it + diff;
        }
        friend Iterator operator-(difference_type diff, const Iterator& it) {
            return it - diff;
        }
        reference operator[](difference_type diff) const { return mPtr[diff]; }

        // std::contiguous_iterator<I>
        pointer operator->() const { return mPtr; }
        using element_type      = T;

    private:
        T* mPtr;
    };

    // === STATIC ASSERTS ===
    // - to verify correct Iterator implementation!
    static_assert(std::weakly_incrementable<Iterator>);
    static_assert(std::input_or_output_iterator<Iterator>);
    static_assert(std::indirectly_readable<Iterator>);
    static_assert(std::input_iterator<Iterator>);
    static_assert(std::incrementable<Iterator>);
    static_assert(std::forward_iterator<Iterator>);
    static_assert(std::bidirectional_iterator<Iterator>);
    static_assert(std::totally_ordered<Iterator>);
    static_assert(std::sized_sentinel_for<Iterator, Iterator>);
    static_assert(std::random_access_iterator<Iterator>);
    static_assert(std::is_lvalue_reference_v<std::iter_reference_t<Iterator>>);
    static_assert(std::same_as<std::iter_value_t<Iterator>,
                  std::remove_cvref_t<std::iter_reference_t<Iterator>>>);
    static_assert(std::contiguous_iterator<Iterator>);


    const T& operator[](int i) const {
        if (i < 0 || i >= SIZE) {
            throw std::runtime_error("Array index out of bounds");
        }
        return mArray[i];
    }

    T& operator[](int i) {
        if (i < 0 || i >= SIZE) {
            throw std::runtime_error("Array index out of bounds");
        }
        return mArray[i];
    }

    Iterator begin()  { return Iterator(&mArray[0]); }
    Iterator end()  { return Iterator(&mArray[SIZE]); }
private:
    T mArray[SIZE];
};

// Check that the Array class can be used as a contiguous_range.
static_assert(std::ranges::contiguous_range<Array<int, 10>>);
```

**NOTE:** `using element_type = T;` was necessary because of a bug in the specification, which might be fixed. I found information about that [here](https://reviews.llvm.org/D101638). Adding this fixed issue with `std::to_address<Iterator>` not being able to compile, and was the last missing piece in going from `std::random_access_iterator` to `std::contiguous_iterator`.

### Testing

I did not perform a complete testing suite with all algorithms, but I chose a few which depend on ranges and `std::random_access_iterator`. It all runs smoothly. I also depend on building standard library headers as module units, because I want to showcase how C++20 features work together.

```cpp
import <stdexcept>;
import <iostream>;
import <iterator>;
import <algorithm>;
import <random>;
#include <memory>    // fails to build header unit!

template<typename T, int SIZE>
class Array
{
    [...]
};

int main()
{
    Array<int, 10> arr;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) arr[i] = i;
    // I need to call std::ragnes::shuffle since that depends on
    // std::random_access_iterator, so that is a minimum.
    // https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/ranges/shuffle
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 gen{rd()};
    std::cout << "before random shuffle:\n";
    for (auto& i : arr) std::cout << i << ' ';
    std::ranges::shuffle(arr, gen);
    std::cout << "\nafter random shuffle:\n";
    for (auto& i : arr) std::cout << i << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';

    // Also std::ranges::stable_sort is a good check (also random_access_iterator):
    // https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/ranges/stable_sort
    std::cout << "after stable_sort:\n";
    std::ranges::stable_sort(arr);
    for (auto& i : arr) std::cout << i << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';

    auto [min,max] = std::ranges::minmax(arr);
    std::cout << "min: " << min << ", max: " << max << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Nicely done. You managed one of the trickier bits: `bool operator==(const Iterator& it)` must be a  `const` member function. This is all still a little rough IMHO, but it is getting better. As mentioned in the comments, simply returning a pointer should be sufficient.

Comment: @GlennTeitelbaum Thank you. The static_cast checks with concepts really makes implementing it easier, compared to earlier. But very often the compiler just wrote "I'm confused" and then stopped parsing. Perhaps true OOP could help make this easier, say like implementing an interface would grant the class certain iterator traits, instead of this nonsense.. I haven't tried just using a pointer, might give it a go. And I'm certainly not going to also implement const_iterator..

Answer (score 1):

As far as I could tell you need typedefs on the iterator class, so simply using a pointer was not sufficient. Here is an example:

```cpp
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

template<typename T, int SIZE>
class Array {
public:
    const T& operator[](int i) const { return mArray[i]; }
    T& operator[](int i) { return mArray[i]; }

private:
    T mArray[SIZE];

public:
struct iterator
{  
    using difference_type=std::ptrdiff_t;
    using value_type=std::remove_cv_t<T>;
    using pointer=T*;
    using reference=T&;
    using iterator_category=std::random_access_iterator_tag;
    using iterator_concept=std::contiguous_iterator_tag;
    using self_type=iterator;

    iterator(T *x) : ptr(x) {}
    T operator*() { return *ptr; }
    T operator->() { return ptr; }
    difference_type operator-(const iterator& rhs) { return ptr-rhs.ptr; }
    iterator& operator ++() { ++ptr; return *this;}
    bool operator !=(const iterator& rhs) { return ptr != rhs.ptr; }
private:
    T * ptr;
};

    iterator begin() { return &mArray[0]; }
    iterator end() { return &mArray[SIZE]; }
};

int foo(Array<int, 7>& a)
{
    int sum;
    for (auto x : a)
    {
        sum+=x;
    }

    return sum;
}

int goo(Array<int, 7>& a, int x)
{
    auto ret=std::find(a.begin(), a.end(), x);
    if (ret!=a.end()) return *ret;
    return 0;
}
```

Note that you would likely need const_iterator and reverse_iterators for const and non-const ...

Comment: This was a great help - thank you!